# How do I add Oracle.NET provider as an option in the provider drop down list?

Tags: oracle, teradata-sql-assistant

I received my replacement system through lifecycle and no longer have Oracle.NET as an option within the Provider's list dropdown. I spent some time researching this issue and haven’t found a solution. What is the best way to add Oracle.NET to this dropdown? My version of Teradata is Teradata SQL Assistant Version 15.10.1.4 (English).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTyex.jpg)

Comment: Which ODP.NET version or Oracle Client version are you on? You can check with `sqlplus -version`, it should be at least 11.2.0.2 for SQL Assistant 15.

Comment: Version 19.4.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can create a User type Data Source via the ODBC connection manager.

Connection Manager > Connect via ODBC > Machine Data Source > New > User Data Source > Oracle in OraHome 19c_client32